# jasmine unit testing a component which has data in a services, where that service fetches data from other service in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have tried to write unit testing of a httpmock one of a service which uses a method (function) to get http get call, but failed to write.

**saveservice.service.ts -- file**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
const envURL = sessionStorage.getItem('apiBaseURL');
 httpGet<T>(url) {
    const URL = envURL + url;
    return this.http.get<T>(URL, httpOptions);
  }
```

this saveservice.service file have httpGET() one, which is used by work.service.ts one

**work.service.ts**

```
import {SaveserviceService } from '../../.././my-service.service';

getworklist(employeeID){

    return this.saveservice.httpGet('work/v1/works?employeeid=' + employeeID);
  }
```

this is how workservice and save service are connected.Now I want to write unit test case for work.component.ts file,but Iam unable to write the httpmock calls there .

For info, apiUrl is present in a different file named env.ts file--
**env.ts**

```
export const apivalue= {

    apiBaseUrl:"https://example.co/",
  };
```

**work.component.ts**

```
ngOnit(){
this.employeeID:this.id;
   this.workservice.getworkList(this.employeeID).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.workList = data;
       console.log(" ggghfghfgh", this.worklist);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);}
```

Above one is work.component.ts file for which i should write unit test cases.Please help me to complete it.

**work.component.spec.ts**

```
 let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
 let injector: Injector;
  let workservice: WorksService;
let saveservice123: SaveService;

 providers: [
        Injector,
        HttpClient,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        saveService,
        worksService
      ],

  httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    workservice = TestBed.get(WorksService);
    saveservice123 = TestBed.get(SaveService)

  fit('getting work detsails indivually', async(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(worksComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    workservice.getworkList(123).subscribe(() =>{});

    const request = httpMock.expectOne("work/v1/works?employeeid=")
    // expect(request.request.method).toBe('httpGet');
    // request.flush(xxxxx);
```

its throwing error

```
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: work/v1/works?employeeGuid=", found none.
```

Please help , how to know to write unit test cases for this type..
I also tried with  spy also,but unable to complete.

```
const mockdata = { id:1, title: "Hello world",  paste: "console.log('Hello world');"}
     const spyOnAdd = spyOn(service, "getworkList").and.returnValue(mockdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your component implements the interface `OnInit` and its method `ngOnint` is renamed to `ngOnInit`.

Your component unit test should not care about how `WorkService` is implemented but entirely concentrate on the behavior of the component (the unit) itself under specified conditions. Therefore you must mock relevant part of the `WorkService`.

Assuming `SaveService` is the only parameter provided to the `WorkService` constructor, the simplest implementation of `work.component.spec.ts` could look as follows.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
...

describe('WorkService', () => {

    const workList = [...]; // specify result of WorkService#getworklist
    const workService = new WorkService(null);
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<WorkComponent>;

    beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {        
        spyOn(workService , 'getworklist').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(workList));
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [...],
            declarations: [WorkComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: WorkService, useValue: workService }
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WorkComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        tick();
    }));

    it('getting work details individually', () => {
        expect(workService.getworklist).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.workList).toEqual(workList);
    });
});
```